# fabricjs not applying filter and size is improper

Tags: javascript, fabricjs

I have a script like:

```
export function filter(url) {
    var c = document.createElement('canvas')
    c.id = "canvas_greyscale"
    var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('canvas_greyscale')
    fabric.Image.fromURL(url, function(oImg) {
        canvas.height = oImg.height
        canvas.width = oImg.width
        oImg.filters.push(new fabric.Image.filters.Grayscale())
        oImg.applyFilters(canvas.renderAll.bind(canvas))
        canvas.add(oImg)
        var img = canvas.toDataURL('image/png')
        console.log(img)
        return img
    }, {crossOrigin: "Anonymous"})
}
```

Here I am applying `grayscale` filter to the image and I want to convert that image to url.

I am getting the url perfectly but the size of the image is not proper.
I am getting only left top part of the image that also without of filter.

What might be wrong here. From the documentation I got this approach to apply filter.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

The only problems I can see are these two lines of code:

```
canvas.setHeight(oImg.height);
canvas.setWidth(oImg.width);
```

I changed your example to render the result in a image, take a look to the runnable snippet below:

```
canvas.height = oImg.height
canvas.width = oImg.width
```

that should be:

```
canvas.setHeight(oImg.height);
canvas.setWidth(oImg.width);
```

and also, since `applyFilters` is asynchronous, I moved your toDataUrl in the callback.

```js
(function filter(url) {
    var c = document.createElement('canvas')
    c.id = "canvas_greyscale"
    var canvas = new fabric.Canvas(c.id)
    fabric.Image.fromURL(url, function(oImg) {
      oImg.width = 100;
      oImg.height = 100;
      canvas.setHeight(oImg.height);
      canvas.setWidth(oImg.width);
      oImg.filters.push(new fabric.Image.filters.Grayscale())
      oImg.applyFilters(
        function(){
         canvas.add(oImg);
         var img = canvas.toDataURL();
         $('#myimg')[0].src = img;
        }
      );
    }, {
      crossOrigin: "Anonymous"
    })
  })('http://i.imgur.com/fHyEMsl.jpg');
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/1.6.4/fabric.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<img id='myimg' />
```